# Which of these 2 subsets is a subspace of R2

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus

- (A) the set of points on the line x + 2y = 0
- (B) the set of points on the line x + 2y = 1

W=set of points line x + 2y = 0 for (A) and x + 2y = 1 for (B)

1. Zero vector
2. U + v is in w?
3. Is cu is in w?

Can anyone explain me briefly or help me to solve this kind of problem with explanation or just answer it and i will be the one to understand the answer itself. This is proving.

Answer (score 4):

In order for a subset to be a subspace,among other things,you need the zero of the vector space to be in the subset.

Now for your subset satisfying $x+2y=1$ we do not have the zero $(0,0)$ included so that is off right away.

Your other set namely points on the line $x+2y=0$ satisfy all properties of the subspace, namely it is closed under addition and scalar multiplication.

Thus it is a subspace.

Comment: Thank you for answering 