# Subset of a vector space which isn't a subspace

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

The content of my exercise says: Show an example of subset U of vector space $\Bbb R^{2} = \Bbb R^{2 \times 1} $ which isn't a subspace of $\Bbb R^{2}$, under conditions:

a) $\forall \space u,v \in U: \space u+v \in U $ ,
$\space \space \space \space \forall \space u \in U: -u \in U $

b) $ \forall  \space \alpha \in \Bbb R \space \land  \forall  \space u \in \Bbb U: \space \alpha*u \in U $

Since these two assumptions together make a definition of a subspace, so in:

a) I will try to find an example which doesn't fullfill a b) condition.
Since $u \in U  \subset \Bbb R$, I can use $\alpha \in \Bbb R \land \alpha\notin U$ to show that.

Let be $U = \Bbb Z, $ For a $\forall \space u \in U \space $ and $ \alpha = \sqrt{2} \space $ Then: $ \sqrt{2}*u\notin \Bbb Z$.
Since it doesn't fullfill second condition of a subspace, $U$ isn't a subspace.

b) I will try to find an example which doesn't fullfil an a) condition.

So I have to show that $ \exists \space (u,v) \in U \subset \Bbb R: \space u+v \notin U. \space $
Then there I'm stuck. My initial thought was set $U$of negative integer numbers, but then for not every $\alpha\in\Bbb R, \space \alpha*u \in U $  - $\alpha$ can be negative too, then outcome will be positive and wouldn't contain in negative numbers set, or $\alpha$ is a root (as I did in a) ), or it's in form of $\frac{1}{x}$, then outcome will not be integer.

My another thought is that since it's $U\in \Bbb R^{2} $, I should look at $u$ as at $(a,b)$ instead but it really didn't help me. Maybe if $U=\{u,v\}$ where $u=(a,-b)$ and $v=(-a,b)$ then: $u+v=(a-a,-b+b)=0$ and $(0,0) \notin U$ but then again I've problem with an $\alpha$.

My intution is telling my to play around the $0$ because  $ \forall  \space \alpha \in \Bbb R: \alpha*0=0 \space$. But honestly I can't produce anything more than I showed there. Thanks in advance, and sorry if something isn't understandable, I'm fairly new to the english maths' nomenclature.

Comment: There are many posts here at this site giving you an answer. So this is, unfortunately, a duplicate. If you can't search, have a look at [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2918560/which-of-these-2-subsets-is-a-subspace-of-r2), or [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4340374/why-this-subset-is-not-a-subspace) for example.

Comment: Take the union of two lines, both containing the origin.

Comment: @DietrichBurde This is a well-written question and it's not immediately obvious why those questions you presented are relevant. I don't think I would have found them either.

Comment: @CyclotomicField I mean that these exercises on subsets of $\Bbb R^2$, whether or not they are subspaces, are so numerous at this site, that almost everything has been said already. Even if the question is "well-written". From Davis's comment we see that such examples are not difficult to find,   too (and also are not new).

Comment: @DietrichBurde it's just that I had to actually read the questions, comments and answers to figure out how it related to this problem. I'm not sure that level of detail is searchable.

It's clear that he's looking for a space that's closed under scalar multiplication but not addition and has put some effort into the problem. For a first time contributor I don't hesitate to call it exceptional. I swear the heavens parted and angels descended from on high for this one.

Comment: @CyclotomicField A agree partly to what you say. So I didn't vote to close. I just think, why not have a look at the hundreds of examples and counterexamples of subsets not being subspaces.

Comment: Before asking the question I looked it up but I didn't really find what I asked for. However I dig deeper into threads linked by @DietrichBurde and they gave me an idea. I will post my solution as soon as I format it, I would appreciate if you give me any feedback is it actually truth since I'm still not sure.

Comment: @DietrichBurde I can see your point. Ultimately goal is to let jlasocha know that their attention to detail and hard work crafting a post that meets and exceeds community guidelines on their first attempt is a wonderful thing. Full problem statement, did all their own markup, showed their own work and stated exactly where they got stuck. Clean readable paragraphs and formatting without community edits. I'm really happy they're here and I hope they stick around.

Comment: @CyclotomicField I had nothing to do with any of this, but I'm bemused by your calling it a "well written"question. I can't figure out what the question is! Maybe "under conditions" in the first sentence is supposed to mean something else - as written the first sentence apears to me to say they want a non-subspace under the condition that it be a subspace

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Sometimes I forget not everyone is fluent in broken English.

Answer (score 1):

An easy example where a) fails but b) is satisfied is the set of points in $\Bbb R^2$ where at least one coordinate is $0$. Multiplying by a constant certainly cannot make that coordinate nonzero, so it remains within this set. On the other hand $\binom03+\binom20=\binom23$ shows that addition, starting with vectors in the set, can get you out of this set. Sets closed under (only) scalar multiplication are called cones, and indeed a usual (double) cone in $\Bbb R^3$ with it apex at the origin is another example.

For the other kind of example (where a) is satisfies but b) fails) you can indeed take $\Bbb Z$ inside $\Bbb R$. Indeed you generally get something where the definition involves some kind of integrality (but not positivity, as you need to be close under taking opposites). Something fancier like $\{\, (x,y)\in\Bbb R^2\mid 3x-5y\in\Bbb Z\,\}$ will work as well.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution to subsection b) of my exercise.**

Let $U$ be set of all polynomials $P(x)=x^2+bx+c$ with any 2 different solutions. (A set of polynomials with $\Delta_{P(x)}>0$).

Since I want $\Bbb R^{2}$ not a $\Bbb R^{3}$ I demand coeffcient of $x^2$ to always be 1 and $b,c \in \Bbb R$ so you can say $u=(b,c)$

$\forall \space \alpha \in \Bbb R: \space \alpha*P(X)\in U$  since multiplying a polynomial by a number doesn't change his solutions.

$\forall \space T(x)\in U \space \space \exists R(x)\in U: T(x)+R(x)=S(x)\notin U \space \space \space \space  (\Delta_{S(x)}<0)$

Example: Let be $\space T(x)= (x - 1) (x - 4)\space$ and $\space R(x)= (x - 5) (x - 9) \space$

Then: $S(x)=T(x)+R(x) \rightarrow S(x)=2x^2-19x+49$

$\Delta_{S(x)}=-31 \implies $ It doesn't have any (real) solutions so $S(x)\notin U$

I think that solution is kinda overkill, and you can probably do it smarter by using  somehow $y=ax+b$ but it is what I've come with.

Comment: If you want the leading coefficient of you polynomial to always be $1$, then the usual rule of multiplying a polynomial by a constant make you leave your set $U$ as soon as you multiply bu a real number other than $1$, so b) is not satisfied, which you wanted. If you take just pairs $(b,c)$ with the vector rules of $\Bbb R^2$, which means your multiplication affects the coefficients $b,c$ but not the leading coefficient $a=1$, then it is no longer true that this multiplication does not affect the number of roots.